# wordpress php redirect user to page if on frontpage

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to redirect my wordpress users to a certain page when they acces the front page.
"Henk" has a page named "henkpage" and "John" has a page named "johnpage".

If the current user is Henk and he's on the front page, then i want that user to be redirected to mydomain.com/henkpage. And same with John: If current user is John and on the frontpage, then redirect to /johnpage. Could anyone help me?

I found this code that might have some usefull lines in them.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $url = wpum_get_profile_url( $current_user );
        wp_redirect( $url ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should work for your purposes, but you'll need to modify this line

`$url = wpum_get_profile_url( $current_user );`

and set `$url` to `$current_user->display_name.'page'` or whatever you'd like it to redirect to.